# Ubuntuforums logs me out, can't post replies

Tags: firefox, linux, ubuntu

I'm using Tor browser bundle (for arch linux, based on firefox esr 24.6.0) off and on.

recently I tried posting on ubuntu forums - I have a valid account, and I can log in and browse, but every time I want to actually post something, forums log me out and I see this message: "The administrator may have required you to register before you can view this page."

I already tried to slacken Tor settings a little (unchecked everything except flash in torbutton -> preferences -> security settings) but the problem remains.

Is there anything I can do?

edit:

Somehow, after completing my registration, I was assigned a new username...
so, I am the same guy who asked the above question.
thanks mirimir for the comment, I was subsequently able to post on ubuntuforums but I suspect it succeeded because I did it only a few seconds after logging in, and not because I visited https://check.torproject.org/ beforehand.

So the question is:
Can I tell Tor to not change nodes randomly?
At least until I finish my business on one forum?
Or would that be too insecure?

Comment: Maybe Tor has switched circuits. Browse https://check.torproject.org/ before you login to Ubuntu Forums, and again after you get the message about needing to register.